# Capturing IP address from a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails form and am trying to capture a client's IP address and ultimately convert that into a zip code.  I've done the following:

**Controller**

```
def create

  ...

  begin
    response = open('https://jsonip.com/').read
    data = JSON.parse(response)
    ip_address = data['ip']
    ip_type = 'jsonip'
  rescue
    ip_type = 'request.remote_ip'
    ip_address = request.remote_ip
  end

  if ip_address
    zip = Geocoder.search(ip_address)
    p "IP Address (#{ip_type}): #{ip_address}, zip: #{zip}"
    @potential_client.zip_code = zip.first.try(:postal) if zip.present?
  end

  ...

end
```

This code came from [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7979#issuecomment-309923614) because `request.remote_ip` kept returning the same IP address.  It seemed to work but once I push to Heroku, it seems like everyone is still coming from the same IP address.

What else am I missing?

Comment: check if this helps you 
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/24521#issuecomment-307484587

Answer (score 1):

With the call to jsonip.com, that is your server rendering and requesting that page so it makes sense that the server IP is returned.

With Heroku and other SaaS providers the remote IP will return the IP of the server or load balancer. Heroku does provide a header "x-forwarded-for" that has a list of IPs the request has passed through.